# How to form a string by replacing dict key with its values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 items in dict, both has list of strings as values, I need to form and print strings by replacing all the substrings matching `_key_` of the dict with its values (all possible combination).

e.g:

```
my_dict['season']=['spring','summer','fall']
my_dict['sport']=['baseball','soccer']

name='bobs-_season_-_sport_'
```

From above, I need to produce below output, by replacing pattern `_season_` and `_sport_` in `name` with all possible value combinations.

```
bobs-spring-baseball
bobs-spring-soccer
bobs-summer-baseball
bobs-summer-soccer
bobs-fall-baseball
bobs-fall-soccer
```

The below code works, but there should be a better way, also need to make this work when I have another item (3rd item) in my_dict. Thanks.

```
>>> my_dict=dict()
>>> my_dict['season']=['spring','summer','fall']
>>> my_dict['sport']=['baseball','soccer']
>>> name='bobs-_season_-_sport_'
>>>
>>> keys_list = list(my_dict.keys())
>>> if len(keys_list) == 2:
...     first_key = keys_list[0]
...     sec_key = keys_list[1]
...     for first_value in my_dict[first_key]:
...         name1 = name
...         if f'_{first_key}_' in name1:
...            name1 = name1.replace(f'_{first_key}_', first_value)
...         for sec_value in my_dict[sec_key]:
...            name2 = name1.replace(f'_{sec_key}_', sec_value)
...            print(name2)
...
bobs-spring-baseball
bobs-spring-soccer
bobs-summer-baseball
bobs-summer-soccer
bobs-fall-baseball
bobs-fall-soccer
```

Comment: do you have a lot of `name`s (as in, do they come from a list) or just one?

Comment: @Boris, there will be only one `name`

Comment: does dict only have those two keys or can it have some unrelated keys that aren't used by this specific code? Like `my_dict['numbers'] = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]` or something.

Comment: It can have unrelated keys too, only if `_key_` match, do replacement, otherwise ignore.

Comment: do you mean that the dictionary might also be missing keys? Like `name = "bobs-_season_-_grade_"` and `"grade"` is missing from the dictionary, in which case the output should be `bobs-spring-_grade_`, `bobs-summer-_grade_` and `bobs-fall-_grade_`?

Comment: @Boris, yes, correct, dict may be missing some keys, like you said above, it won't be replaced then.

Answer (score 1):

You can use itertools.product to generate the different cases :

```
import itertools
my_dict = {}
my_dict['season']=['spring','summer','fall']
my_dict['sport']=['baseball','soccer']

name='bobs-_season_-_sport_'

for values in itertools.product(*my_dict.values()):
    new_name = name
    for key, value in zip(my_dict.keys(), values):
        new_name = new_name.replace(f'_{key}_', value)
    print(new_name)
```

Note that you need Python 3.6+ to ensure that dictionary insertion order is kept.

Comment: This will produce a bunch of duplicates and take a long time to run if `my_dict` has other keys that aren't used for this specific task, because you're generating conminations of all the values in the dict, even if most aren't used.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you split the problem up into two parts. The first parses your input string (`name`) to figure out which keys it needs to use for replacements later. Then in a second step, you calculate all the combinations of values and do the substitutions.

I suggest using regular expressions for the parsing:

```
import re

keys = re.findall(r'_([^_]+)_', name)
```

Now make the combinations using `itertools.product`:

```
for values in itertools.product(*[my_dict[key] for key in keys]):
    output = name
    for key, value in zip(keys, values):
        output = output.replace("_{}_".format(key), value)
    print(output)
```

If you can choose the format you're using in `name`, a much nicer one (for your code) would be `bob-{season}-{sport}` because you can use it directly as a format string (rather than needing to repeatedly call `str.replace`). Using that style of input, you could replace the code above with:

```
keys = re.findall(r'\{([^}]+)\}', name)
for values in itertools.product(*[my_dict[key] for key in keys]):
    print(name.format(**dict(zip(keys, values))))
```

I see in a recent comment that your dictionary may not always have keys for all of the key strings in `name`. If that's the case, then you should use `my_dict.get(key, ['_{}_'.format(key)])` instead of `my_dict[key]` in the list comprehension inside of the `product` call. This will replace `_unknownkey_` with itself, since there's nothing else to use instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re` for finding the keys in the string, then create a suitable template string and use `itertools.product` for creating the value tuples:

```
from functools import reduce
import itertools as it
import re

keys = re.findall(r'_([a-z]+)_', name)
template = reduce(lambda s, k: s.replace(f'_{k}_', '{}'), keys, name)
result = list(template.format(*x) for x in it.product(*[my_dict[k] for k in keys]))
```

Or you can use `it.starmap` in place of the last line, if you find it clearer:

```
result = list(it.starmap(template.format, it.product(*[my_dict[k] for k in keys])))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this using list comprehensions

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

```
my_dict=dict()
my_dict['season']=['spring','summer','fall']
my_dict['sport']=['baseball','soccer']
name='bobs-_season_-_sport_'

def generate_all_replaced(name, d):
    names = [name]
    for k in d.keys():
        names = [n.replace(f'_{k}_', v) for v in d[k] for n in names]
    return names


print(generate_all_replaced(name, my_dict))
```